# Actions on Google NO_MATCH handling

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

In the Actions Console one can specify a NO_Match when a user's response does not match an existing parameter. But that NO_MATCH does not provide a transition to another scene. When the user input is not recognized, I want to return to the start of the conversation and start over. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem odd that the only transition that NO_MATCH supports in the Actions Builder/SDK is to the (mandatory) End Conversation scene. But this is more a conceptual notion - NO_MATCH indicates that you want to attempt conversation recovery, or that you're giving up on it.

If you want to capture what is said and/or take action on it (ie - transition to a different scene) you can do something like this:

1. Create a Type that takes "Free form text" (I usually call it "Any"), by creating a type and selecting this for "What kind of values" will it support.

[image: Any Intent]

2. Create an Intent where all the sample phrases use this Any type - I've named it "fallback" in this example. You should specify that this is *not* a global Intent, since we only want it explicitly triggered in a Scene. Then create an intent parameter that uses the Any type and some sample phrases that use this parameter.  Make sure you highlight some of the words in the phrases to show which parts are the "Any" type, since they won't automatically match.

[image: fallback intent]

3. Finally, in your scene, place this as the last Custom Intent. (Note that it *must* be the last Custom Intent, since they are evaluated in order.) You can then assign it to transition to whatever scene you want.

[image: scene]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried your solution without success:

Comment: openChooseType
{
  "userInput": {
    "originalQuery": "zzzz"
  },
  "responses": []
}
Session storage
{}
User storage
{}

Comment: interactionMatch
openChooseType
{
  "interactionMatch": {
    "intentId": "actions.intent.NO_MATCH_1"
  },
  "responses": [
    {
      "firstSimple": {
        "speech": "No match found 11",
        "text": "No match found 11"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I note that "Test Query" responds when a Test Phrase is entered that matches the Intent's free form text Test Phrase. But the scene drops out to No_Match when any other text is entered.

Comment: You may want to double-check the test - sometimes the test simulator takes a little bit to update. If you're still having the problem, please update the question with screen shots of the Type, Intent, Scene, and simulator showing the error. (Trying to see errors in the comments are pretty difficult.)

Comment: I have a screen shot. How do I add it here? It doesn't paste.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that you need 100 reputation to upload a picture. You can, however, put it anywhere that is public and link to it.

Comment: Would it help if I shared the project with you on GCP?

Comment: That won't help others who, in the future, might have the same problem. Posting the images it a good first step.

Comment: I started over in debugging by setting Words and Phrases in the problem Intent rather than free form text. Actions correctly understands input from the intent Training Phrases but does not recognize the associated Type's words, returning instead a NO_MATCH. The Type seems to be disconnected from the Intent. I'll send screens tomorrow.

Comment: I went back to square one and deleted all scenes, intents and types except two working sets. I created a new scene, intent and type to handle free form input i.e. a word like "nonsense" that is not in any of the two working types phrases or keys or values. Inputting "nonsense" took me to the NO_MATCH routine that I don't want. Testing the query in the Intent with "nonsense" didn't work either. However, adding "nonsense" to my new intent's training phrases did take me to my own no match scene. So it appears that the Intent has to be satisfied before the Type. But that's not free form input...

Comment: I have to say that this effort is made immensely harder by the lack of adequate debugging tools, versioning and intelligible documentation. Two new videos won't hack it for me.

Comment: I found the issue. In the error handling intent I failed to highlight the training phrases and associate them with the Type. No syntax error or any other indication that this would be a problem. Ah, the joys of new releases...

Comment: Glad you figured the problem out! I've updated my point 2 to make it more clear that you need to highlight parts of the phrase to match the Any parameter. If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! Your response was rapid as well as pointing the way to a solution.